# Error in the connect function BlackBerry-10

Tags: c++, http, blackberry-10

Hi I am trying to send an HTTP GET request and receive the result with a function. But I am getting this error:

> no matching function for call to 'HttpNetworkRequest::connect(QNetworkAccessManager*&, const char*, RequestFinishFunction&, const 
>        char*)'

the connect function is in this HttpNetworkRequest.cpp file

```
#include "HttpNetworkRequest.hpp"
#include <QObject>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QDir>

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>
#include <bb/cascades/XmlDataModel>
#include <RequestFinishFunction.hpp>
using namespace bb::cascades;

HttpNetworkRequest::HttpNetworkRequest(bb::cascades::Application *app)
: QObject(app)
{
QNetworkRequest networkRequest = QNetworkRequest();
networkRequest.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.blackberry.com"));
RequestFinishFunction req;
QNetworkAccessManager *networkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
bool res =        connect(networkAccessManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    req,SLOT(requestFinished()));
Q_ASSERT(res);
Q_UNUSED(res);
networkAccessManager->get(networkRequest);
}
```

The included RequestFinishFunction.hpp

```
#ifndef REQUESTFINISHFUNCTION_HPP_
#define REQUESTFINISHFUNCTION_HPP_
#include <bb/cascades/ActivityIndicator>
#include <QObject>
#include <QObject>
class RequestFinishFunction : QObject
{
public slots:
void requestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);
};
#endif /* REQUESTFINISHFUNCTION_HPP_ */
```

The RequestFinishFunction.cpp file is

```
#include <bb/cascades/ActivityIndicator>
#include <QObject>
#include <QObject>
#include <RequestFinishFunction.hpp>
void RequestFinishFunction::requestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of connect method

> bool QObject::connect ( const QObject * sender, const char * signal, const QObject * receiver, const char * method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection )

We have to pass ***references*** of both sender & receiver.

You didn't send reference of receiver. You have two options to do so.

1) Send reference of req using & operator in connect method call

Replace

> connect(networkAccessManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), req,SLOT(requestFinished()));

with

> connect(networkAccessManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &req,SLOT(requestFinished()));

**OR**

2) Declare req as pointer

Replace

> RequestFinishFunction req;

with

> RequestFinishFunction *req;

Comment: THanks for the reply. After doing that I've got "no matching function for call to 'HttpNetworkRequest::connect(QNetworkAccessManager*&, const char*, RequestFinishFunction*, const 
  char*)'" this error message.

Comment: If you have declared it as pointer, don't use & operator in method call.

Comment: As per your code, call to connect method should be exactly like this
connect(networkAccessManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    &req,SLOT(requestFinished()));

Comment: bool res = connect(networkAccessManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),&req,SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));  this is how I have done it now. and I got "no matching function for call to 'HttpNetworkRequest::connect(QNetworkAccessManager*&, const char*, RequestFinishFunction*, const char*)'" this error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21327/discussion-between-kalkin-and-sorry-boss)